# Trying to use gnome-shell but it will not work

Tags: gnome

It acts like it wants to work, but all I get is the bar across the top with "activities", the time, my name, and the background. After that my computer will do nothing else.

I installed it following the directions [here](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/DistributionPackages), detailing how to install it on Ubuntu (have tried the repository version and the PPA version).

Graphics card information:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
```

Comment: How did you go about installing `gnome-shell`? Also how did you go about running it?

Comment: Graphic card information and anything interesting from the Xorg.log would help as well.

Comment: Oddly enough it works on my desktop, which are obviously two completely different computers... So I am guessing that maybe it is a hardware issue on my laptop...

Comment: Have you tried running the Unity interface? Seeing as both use Mutter as a window manager (currently) it would be interesting to know if Unity works...

Comment: @fluteflute I don't think that's correct: Unity shows up as a Compiz plugin. I'm pretty sure it's running Compiz (Fusion) as the window manager.

Comment: @NicholasFlynt At the time of this post (twelve months ago) then Unity used Mutter. Things have changed since... :)

Comment: @fluteflute I should really check the timestamps before committing necromancy :D Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by re-installing ubuntu... makes me wonder if I got rid of something it depended on by accident..

Answer (score 1):

You can report such bugs by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then entering `ubuntu-bug gnome-shell`. This will allow the developers to help improve Ubuntu. (The same procedure is used for any application.) This automatically adds your hardware information to the report.

Note: you need to remove the PPA version, and have the version from the standard repositories installed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you delete your hidden ~/.gnome* folder(s) and Gnome does not have what to show.

Solution: start in Ubuntu live cd and copy the hidden ~/.gnome* folder(s) from the cd to your hard drive user folder.

Alternatively copy from the root folder to the user folder.

Then boot from hard-disk and create launchers to recover lost shortcuts.

Comment: This did not work. I did not delete it, and it was present... But I replaced it with the vanilla one anyways...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is probably a hardware issue with your graphics card. Sometimes the shell freezes when mutter doesn't like your graphics driver. Report a bug on the GNOME bugzilla so the developers can possibly find a workaround.

On another note, the technology for GNOME Shell is still a bit immature right now, and mileage will vary. Reporting a bug about your issue should help them to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, press alt+f2 and type:

> gksudo gedit

When gedit opens, open the file "/etc/environment". Paste the following text on a new line:

> export CLUTTER_VBLANK=none

Save the file and reboot. This works enabling some clutter related features for me, and I have this exact chipset. Though I will say Gnome Shell works for me by default so.. :/

Comment: As you say yourself, this is unrelated to the problem at hand.

Comment: That makes no sense.. It might very well be a problem. It fixes other clutter related issues for me.